# Use of isinstance() can overwrite type

Tags: python, python-3.x, overwrite, isinstance

Use of `isinstance()` changed the class type of `dict`
Why is this happening? I know using builtins would prevent but I want to understand better why this is happening.

```
250     def printPretty(records,num,title='Summary:'):
251         import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
252         if isinstance(records, list):
253             print ("\n{}\n{}".format(title.center(120),"="*120))
254             table = list()
255             for i in records:
...
263         elif isinstance(records, dict):
264  ->         for key in records:
265                 if isinstance(records[key], Param):
266                     for i in records[key]:
267                         print (i)
268                 print ("")
269     
(Pdb) type(records)
<class 'dict'>
(Pdb) type(dict)
<class 'type'><b>
```

Comment: `isinstance` won't change the type of things. Nothing here indicates that anything's type has been changed.

Comment: Why do you think any type change has happened?

Comment: Your question suggests that you're expecting some different results from the `type` calls you're making at the end, but it's not clear what you expect instead. Can you clarify what you expected and why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/6581949#6581949

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion lies in the fact that `type(dict) != dict`.  Lets discard your example entirely except for the last two lines, which I will use interactive python to present.

```
>>> type(dict)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(dict())
<type 'dict'>
```

This is because `dict` is not a dictionary, but the type of dictionaries.  `dict()` or `{}` (or `{1:2, ...}`) are instances of dictionaries.  These instances have type of `dict`, and satisfy `isinstance(___, dict)`.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly right, I was confused and your answer clarified.